Blender 4.1 python-controlled sculpt brush strokes: how do I get strokes instead of dabs?
I'm writing a script to generate brush thumbnails for my library of alpha brushes. I can't figure out how to make proper brush strokes (continuous movements) with Python - only individual dabs in XYZ space.
The OperatorStrokeElement documentation only lists the struct members, not what they represent or how to use them, and the bpy.ops.sculpt.brush_stroke documentation is also sparse.
When I input three stroke elements, I expected the output to be a bent line, defined by the three points.

Instead I get three dabs on the sphere.

I've included a python script below that clears the scene, creates a subdivided icosphere, and applies sculpt.brush_stroke with the OperatorStrokeElement List as the input (using the currently selected brush, I suggest the Draw brush for simplicity).
You can see in the code where I've experimented with the mouse and mouse_event properties.
I thought some combination of mouse and mouse_event might describe the gesture the "virtual mouse" made after "clicking" but that isn't happening. Changing these properties has no result.
What I've discovered experimentally:
location is definitely (x,y,z) coordinates indicating where the mouse click is read - it must be placed on the surface of the object, it is not projected like actual mouse gestures are.
pen_flip can be used to invert the brush from positive to negative (or vice versa)
pressure corresponds to the pressure by the virtual pen.
size, time, x_tilt, y_tilt: seem to all be ignored
NOTE: I can make a ton of small dabs to describe a shape, but the result will be wrong - it forces a result as if "Accumulate" is turned on. The results are even more wrong if you use a stroke type other than "Stroke" or apply a texture to the brush.
----
EDIT: I experimented some more
with the yellow ("elastic") brushes, the mouse and mouse_event properties seem to produce results. mouse_event seems to describe the delta between the start and the end of the stroke, not entirely sure what mouse represents in this case.

If you use the mask brush, Blender crashes.
import bpy
import numpy as np
import pprint

def get_center_of_viewport():
    # Get the dimensions of the Blender windowarea_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    area_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    center_x = 0.0
    center_y = 0.0
    areas  = [area for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas if area.type == area_type]
    if len(areas) <= 0:
        raise Exception(f"Make sure an Area of type {area_type} is open or visible in your screen!")

    with bpy.context.temp_override(
        window=bpy.context.window,
        area=areas[0],
        region=[region for region in areas[0].regions if region.type == 'WINDOW'][0],
        screen=bpy.context.window.screen
    ):
        width = bpy.context.area.width
        height = bpy.context.area.height

        # Calculate the center
        center_x = width / 2
        center_y = height / 2
        print(f"Center: ({center_x},{center_y})")
    return (center_x, center_y)

class BrushStrokeThumbnailer:
    def __init__(self, path, scene='Scene', brush='Draw', subdivisions=8):
        self.path = path
        self.scene = scene
        self.brush = brush
        self.subdivisions = subdivisions
        self.mode = 'OBJECT'
        self.sphere = bpy.context.active_object

    def clear_slate(self):
        print('   clear_slate()')
        #store mode
        try:
            self.mode = bpy.context.active_object.mode 
        except:
            print("Assuming OBJECT")
            self.mode = 'OBJECT'

        # Clear all objects
        try:
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
        except:
            pass
        
        for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
            obj.select_set(True)
        bpy.ops.object.delete()
        print("cleared objects")

        old_objs = set(bpy.data.objects)
        
        # Create basic ico_sphere with N subdivisions
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_ico_sphere_add(subdivisions=self.subdivisions)
        new_objs = set(bpy.data.objects) - old_objs
        self.sphere = list(new_objs)[0]
        self.sphere.select_set(True)
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = self.sphere
        bpy.context.object.name = "Brush_Thumbnail.object"
        
        bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.sculpt.use_symmetry_x = False
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode=self.mode)
        return self
    
    
    def stroke(self):
        print('   stroke()')
        cont = bpy.context.area.type  
        try:
            # Apply stroke
            area_type = 'VIEW_3D'
            areas  = [area for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas if area.type == area_type]
            if len(areas) <= 0:
                raise Exception(f"Make sure an Area of type {area_type} is open or visible in your screen!")

            with bpy.context.temp_override(
                window=bpy.context.window,
                area=areas[0],
                region=[region for region in areas[0].regions if region.type == 'WINDOW'][0],
                screen=bpy.context.window.screen
            ):
                bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='SCULPT')
                bpy.ops.sculpt.brush_stroke(stroke=strokes, mode='NORMAL', ignore_background_click=False)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Failed to perform brush stroke:", e)
            print("   context:", e.__context__)
            print("   traceback:", e.__traceback__)
            print(str(cont))
        
        return self

    def execute(self):
        print('   execute()')
        #store mode
        try:
            self.mode = bpy.context.active_object.mode 
        except:
            bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.data.objects[0]
            self.mode = bpy.context.active_object.mode 
        
        self = self.clear_slate().stroke()        

        #restore mode
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode=self.mode)
        
        return self

center_x, center_y = get_center_of_viewport()
strokes = [{'is_start': True,
 'location': (0.758774, -0.651354, 0),
 'mouse': (center_x, center_y),
 'mouse_event': (center_x, center_y),
 'name': 'stroke.1',
 'pen_flip': False,
 'pressure': 2.0,
 'size': 1,
 'time': 10,
 'x_tilt': 0.5,
 'y_tilt': 0.5},
{'is_start': False,
 'location': (1, 0, 0),
 'mouse': (0, 0),
 'mouse_event': (300, 300),
 'name': 'stroke.9',
 'pen_flip': False,
 'pressure': .5,
 'size': 1,
 'time': 10,
 'x_tilt': 0,
 'y_tilt': 0},
{'is_start': False,
 'location': (.8869, -0.3602, .2891),
 'mouse': (300, 300),
 'mouse_event': (0, 0),
 'name': 'stroke.9',
 'pen_flip': False,
 'pressure': .75,
 'size': 1,
 'time': 10,
 'x_tilt': 0,
 'y_tilt': 0}]

BrushStrokeThumbnailer(strokes, scene='Scene', subdivisions=8).execute()


